# Does Hogwarts have any transfer students?

Tags: harry-potter

Were there any students who, unlike Harry and company, began their Wizarding education at another school (perhaps Durmstang or Beauxbatons), then moved to the UK and began attending Hogwarts as a transfer student?

Comment: None that we're aware of. Some apparently "study away" if they want to gain specialist knowledge